Non metrizable uniform spaces
Bourbaki's book on general topology states that a uniform space is metrizable iff it is Hausdorff and the filter of entourages of the uniformity has a countable basis. However, he doesn't provide an example of a uniform space that is not metrizable. So I'm looking for examples of uniform spaces that aren't metrizable. If there are no important examples, then I don't see the motivation to study uniform spaces. I appreciate your help!

An infinite-dimensional Banach space (say, $\ell^2$) equipped with the weak topology has a natural uniform space structure, and it is not metrizable.

@DavidGao, do you have some bibliography where I can study that with detail?

Since you are already reading Bourbaki, you may want to check the chapter on Topological Vector Spaces

@RataMágica I come from a background in functional analysis, so unfortunately no, I don't know of any good references for studying this from a uniform space perspective.

It is known that every compact Hausdorff topological space admits exactly one uniformity (induced by all (finite) open covers). The notion of metrizability of a compact Hausdorff topological space agrees with metrizability of the corresponding uniform space. Hence any nonmetrizable compact Hausdorff topological space answers your question. Such spaces can be build up e.g. using Tychonoff theorem (as uncountable products) or as Čech-Stone compactification of a noncompact Tychonoff space.

Every topological group comes with several useful uniform structures (left, right, etc). They are metrizable if and only if the topology of the group is. If you want to study details, you can start with "Uniform structures on topological groups and their quotients" by Roelcke and Dierolf (1981).

For more examples and motivation, see "Uniform ideas in analysis" by M.D. Rice, Real Analysis Exchange 6 (1980/81), 139--185.

The paper referenced by @user95282: Rice - Uniform ideas in analysis.  (It has DOI 10.2307/44133008, which is what I would normally link, but, despite the article being open access, the DOI takes me to a JStor page that insists that I log in to "an institution".)

@LSpice "Uniform ideas in analysis" by M.D. Rice is available here:                          https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-6/issue-2/

@user95282, re, yes, thanks, that's my first link to the article (second in the comment).

I would advise the reading of Counterexamples in Topology, by Steen & Seebach, [MR1382863], and in particular of example 44 on page 70. Also in Bourbaki's Topologie générale. Chapitres 5 à 10,[MR3822133], besides Théorème 1 on page TG IX.15, you will find Exercice 7 on page TG IX.91.

Today 49 different examples of such spaces may be found at π-Base, Search for Uniformizable+~Metrizable+$T_2$.
I think an elementary example would be S22
Fortissimo Space on the Real Numbers, $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$, where each point of $\mathbb R$ is isolated and neighborhoods of $\infty$ are co-countable. Basic entourages are of the form $\Delta\cup U^2$ where $\Delta$ is the diagonal and $U$ is a neighborhood of $\infty$. Note that there is no countable basis for this uniformity, as if there were, the space would be first countable; however, there is no countable base of neighborhoods for $\infty$.
